# Trying to pull useful info blocks from text file

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to pull all of the occurrences of a certain table out of a text file using string slices, but it keeps pulling out the first slice over and over.

Perhaps I need a dummy variable for the start and end counts?

```
result = ''  
start = 'start of stuff I want'  
end = 'end of stuff I want'  
otn = o.read()  
count = otn.count(start)  
s = 0  
e = 0  
for i in range(count):  
    s = otn.find(start, s)  
    e = otn.find(end, s)  
    result = result + otn[s:e]  
print(result)
```

Any advice?

Comment: look at the values of s and e after the finds

Comment: o is just the file that I am opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  It's more python-y and reusable:

```
def extract_delimited_data(data, begin_delimiter, end_delimiter):
    s = data.find(begin_delimiter)

    while s != -1:
        e = data.find(end_delimiter, s + len(begin_delimiter))

        s += len(begin_delimiter)
        yield data[s:e]

        s = data.find(begin_delimiter, e + len(end_delimiter))

data = 'foo<bar>hello<world>'

print list(extract_delimited_data(data, '<', '>'))
```

Outputs:

```
['bar', 'world']
```

Comment: I think you want to do s += len(begin_delimiter) there, right? Otherwise you include the delimiter in the return.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: I cannot parse that sentence.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Yes, I missed the length consideration.

Comment: Instead of `while s != -1:
        s += 1`, you probably want `while s != -1:
        s += len(begin_delimiter)`

Comment: I am talking about this: "Just a note for those who aren't cool enough for Py3k -- you'll have to append s string which is defined before 'while' instead of using yield."  I have no idea what meaning you are trying to convey.

Comment: NM. I spend most of my time in Python 3 and was lead to believe that it was new for that version.

Comment: That is a way better generalized version than what I was using. Thanks for the help, new to python, only other experience was with matlab and mathematica which didn't involve much string work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the second parameter to find should be s + 1. find will find things at or after the given index, so if the given index points to a match, it will just find it again.

The initial value of s should therefore be -1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
for i in range(count):  
    s = otn.find(start, e)  #start looking after the end of the previous data
    e = otn.find(end, s)    #start looking after the above beginning
    result = result + otn[s:e]
```